# Cost of Developing Bluetooth 4.0 BLE applications for iOS or OSX?

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have HW applications that uses BLE i.e. Bluetooth 4.0. I would like to get it working in Apple products such as iOS or OSX. My friend said that earlier developers had to be pay at least some 20k USD + margin of profits to get their hardware device accepted by Apple. The services have online frontend and specific hardware that are supposed be connected via BLE to phones/laptops.

*What is the cost currently to develop BLE services for Apple?*

Comment: Please explain "accepted by Apple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLE devices do not require Apple's [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) certification (which is apparently $20k+). Your only costs would be standard [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) ($100) and the cost of developing the actual app to communicate with your BLE device.

From Apple's [MFi FAQ](http://mfi.apple.com/faqs#4-2):

> **I want to develop an accessory that communicates with an Apple device
>   using only Bluetooth Low Energy. Do I need to join the MFi Program?**
>
> No. Accessories which connect to an Apple device using only Bluetooth
>   Low Energy/BTLE/Bluetooth 4.0 or standard Bluetooth profiles supported
>   by iOS are not part of the MFi Program.